# Filtering output on nested object property in Powershell

Tags: powershell, object-graph

I have a nested set of data that I am trying to get a nested value to evaluate with the where-object clause that looks like:

`$configs | Where-Object {$_.data.attributes.property -eq 'value'}`

I have learnt that nested objects don't work like this.

I have tried doing nested select statements like:

`($configs | Where-Object {($_.data | select attributes | select 'property') -eq 'value'})`

And tried using the in memory where() function like this:

`$configs.where({$_.data.where{$_.attributes.where{$_.'property' -ne 'value'}}})`

These don't return no data as I would have expected from an invalid script block, but they will return all data with no filtering, even if I change -eq to -ne it returns the same thing.

`$configs.data.attributes | ?{$_.property -eq 'value'}` returns the list of what I would expect, but I need the output to include the data from the base `$config` variable, not just the data in the attributes nested object.

How can I use the where-object clause on a nested object property?

Sample data of $config:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "12345678",
      "type": "configurations",
      "attributes": {
        "organization-id": 1234657,
        "organization-name": "organization",
        "resource-url": "https://subdomain.domain.com/1234567/item/12345678",
        "restricted": false,
        "psa-integration": "enabled",
        "my-glue": false,
        "name": "Simple Switch01",
        "hostname": null,
        "primary-ip": null,
        "mac-address": null,
        "default-gateway": null,
        "serial-number": null,
        "asset-tag": null,
        "position": null,
        "installed-by": null,
        "purchased-by": null,
        "notes": null,
        "operating-system-notes": null,
        "warranty-expires-at": null,
        "installed-at": null,
        "purchased-at": null,
        "created-at": "2017-10-20T03:01:20Z",
        "updated-at": "2022-03-12T07:05:39Z",
        "organization-short-name": "organization",
        "configuration-type-id": 193614,
        "configuration-type-name": "Managed Switch",
        "configuration-type-kind": "switch",
        "configuration-status-id": 13313,
        "configuration-status-name": "Active",
        "manufacturer-id": null,
        "manufacturer-name": null,
        "model-id": null,
        "operating-system-id": null,
        "operating-system-name": null,
        "location-id": 3134450,
        "location-name": "Lower Hutt",
        "contact-id": 7683204,
        "archived": false,
        "model-name": null,
        "contact-name": "name"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "adapters-resources": {
          "data": [
            "@{id=617978337; type=adapters_resources}"
          ]
        },
        "passwords": {
          "data": []
        },
        "attachments": {
          "data": []
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "included": [],
  "meta": {
    "current-page": 1,
    "next-page": 2,
    "prev-page": null,
    "total-pages": 8482,
    "total-count": 8482,
    "filters": {}
  },
  "links": {
    "self": "self link",
    "next": "next link",
    "last": "last link"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us an example of how you obtained the `$configs` data so we can work with that

Comment: If that is too complicated, then at least show us what `$config` looks like as JSON for instance

Comment: You can get an object as JSON like this: `$configs | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5`. If the output is too long, than a few snippets of that would still be useful.

Comment: Sorry, have added the data what $config contains

Comment: The data was obtained from an invoke-restmethod call to an API endpoint - https://api.itglue.com/developer/#configurations-index

Comment: Neither `property` nor  `value` appears in your JSON - what are you looking for?

Comment: property is 'psa-integration' and value is either enabled or orphaned

Comment: Then something like `$config | Where-Object {$_.data.attributes.'psa-integration' -eq 'enabled'  }` should work (pass `$config` to `ConvertFrom-Json` if it is JSON).

Comment: That's what I initially tried, but it doesn't seem to actually filter, it just returns everything regardless of the operator. The data is in an object that invoke-restmethod made initially.

Comment: Well, that's the logic of the `Where-Object` call as you're trying to use it: `$config` is a _single object_, and if the criterion matches, that single object is output. Please edit your question to clarify the _desired output_.

Comment: Thanks @mklement10, that actually answered my question. I was ignoring the fact that the base level was a single object which was being returned.